# Insert in nested field

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm a new user in LINQ to SQL and I have some problems using it. 
I've used LINQ to SQL Designer and I have created my classes, mapped on the DB tables.
In particular, I have one class, named voice:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.voce")]
public partial class voce : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _id_voce;

    ... other private fields;



    private int _category;

    private EntityRef<category> _category1;
            public voce()
    {
        this._riepilogo = new EntitySet<riepilogo>(new Action<riepilogo>(this.attach_riepilogo), new Action<riepilogo>(this.detach_riepilogo));
        this._hera = default(EntityRef<hera>);
        this._category1 = default(EntityRef<category>);
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_id_voce", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int id_voce
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id_voce;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._id_voce != value))
            {
                this.Onid_voceChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._id_voce = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("id_voce");
                this.Onid_voceChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    ......
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_category", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int category
    {
        get
        {
            return this._category;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._category != value))
            {
                if (this._category1.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                {
                    throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                }
                this.OncategoryChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._category = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("category");
                this.OncategoryChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, voce class has a field named category that refers to a table named category.

When I add a new voce to my database, I create a new voce istance and, using the DataContext, i simply add it, using:

```
voce v = new voce(){...field, category1 = //create or retrieve category};
```

In particular, the category field is retrieved from the DB if already exists or, if not, it is inserted, before I insert the voice.

The problem is that when I add the voice in the database:

```
datacontext.InsertOnSubmit(v);
datacontext.SubmitChanges();
```

it inserts the category again, failing with the unique contraint.

How can I add a voice without adding every nested object?

Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I feel like the problem could be in `//create or retrieve category`. It is probably always creating the new category or not returning the one atached to your current `datacontext`. Could you post the code for that method?

Answer (score 0):

```
internal category GetCategoryFromDescription (string desc, Utility.VOICE_MODALITY mode)
    {
        bool type = mode == Utility.VOICE_MODALITY.ENTRATA ? true : false;
        var query = from cat in dc.category
                    where cat.description == desc && cat.type == type
                    select cat;

        if (query.Count() == 0)
        {
            category newC =  new category() { description = desc };
            dc.category.InsertOnSubmit(newC);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            return newC;
        }
        else
            return query.Single();

    }
```